# SproutCore javascript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, frameworks, spry, sproutcore

Hey... I started using Javascript MVC SproutCore Framework (sproutcore.com) and I found it impressive. But...

1. Where can I find good tutorials for it?
2. Where can I find widgets for it?
3. How can I use (best practice, loading librarys, implementation) other frameworks like Spry framework (http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/).

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The only tutorial I know of is [the Todos tutorial](http://wiki.sproutcore.com/Todos%C2%A0Intro), which I believe is not currently completable from *Incremental Loading* point onward.
2. The widgets available are in `/frameworks/desktop/views` (the root here is the repository base). If you want something more complex (e.g. a calendar widget), you'd have to write it yourself using the widgets in that directory as examples.
3. I don't understand this question, but you should be able to use Spry simply by loading it into the page. SproutCore isn't a particularly good global citizen and I've not looked at Spry but I don't expect you'll see conflicts. If you're looking for Sproutcore documentation on best practices/loading/implementation, there isn't any. You have to read the source of the libary/test suite/demos to figure that sort of thing out.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sproutcore.com/static/sample_controls/

Answer (score 0):

@1 Did you already check the [SproutCore Wiki](http://wiki.sproutcore.com/) and the [SproutCore10-Introduction](http://wiki.sproutcore.com/SproutCore10-Introduction)?

On the right hand side you have a navigator and sidebar-links for the documentation.